# I can't work with Maven's dependency in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

[image]

Hi, all! My problem is that I cant't work with Maven's dependency in IntelliJ IDEA (see the picture). What's wrong? This error does not depend on Link library. I tried t odo reimport. It was useless.

Comment: Did you convert your project into Maven Project?

Comment: IntelliJ will take some time to resolve and download it. Try mvn idea:idea on your project

Comment: Abu Sufian, No. I don't. I created a new Maven project.

Comment: did you try `mvn clean install` in below terminal.

Comment: Try maven/reimport (on project folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure that Firewall/Any other software is not preventing IntelliJ Idea from connecting to internet.**

The Dependency is not yet downloaded and installed to the `local .m2 repository`, so `intelliJ` needs internet connectivity so that it can download the dependency for the first time!

*Once downloaded to local repository, you can work offline!*

then try `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Thanks. I did following things:

Comment: (1) Downloaded "Maven" from Maven's site and installed it (2) Set enviroment variables PATH for WIndows for Java  and Maven (3) Turn off Firewall (4) run command  "mvn clean install" in my project. Now it works

Answer (score 3):

Try pressing 'Reimport All Maven Projects' button. It's the first button at Maven Projects tab (blue circle).
Looks like this dependency wasn't downloaded from Internet yet.

Comment: Wow that helped me! Thanks.